# Randomly missing QR codes missing from label

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers, zpl

My problem is that the QR Code is missing on some of the labels. My ZPL Code looks as follows.

```
^XA
^CI27
^CWY,ARIALSMY.FNT
^FO697,101
^BXN,5,200,26,26,,_,^FH^FD_44_45_41_85_00_00_00_00_14_A0_02_0D_73_B6_00_E8_28_25_85_91_07_68_62_B4_B9_A9_9B_85_68_93_26_78_24_6A_7F_5F_B9_64_7B_E6_00_00^FS
^XZ
```

Why is it missing on this label when i print it but it is visible if i put it in the ZPL online viewer?

Comment: What is the size of the label stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else has a similar problem.
We use underscore as our escape character.

```
^BXN,5,200,26,26,,_,
```

So if the code contains Hex 5F the code wont work / wont show up.
that is also the case with any other character we would use. So we doubled the Character and the code now works in every case.

`if (qrCode.Contains("_5F"))//5F is hex for underscore
          qrCode.Replace("_5F", "_5F_5F");`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is the ^FO part of your code. It specifies the coordinates to 697 dots to the right and 101 pixels down from your 'home' coordinate. I you don't specify this in your ZPL code it will be whatever the last time it was stored, i.e it can be anything.

What's probably happening is that you are printing outside of printable area. Try changing those two values down (or up) and see if the can get your print inside your label. If you don't succeed try adding a ^LH0,0 to your code and work from a known origin. Be careful though as this will affect any other label being printed on this printer and it will change the default home position.

So try. `^FO0,0` and go from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sadly the same coordinates work with a different code. The only difference between the working and not working code is the FD value.